# Convert an array into an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring, javascript-objects

Exists a more elegant way to create an object from an array than this one?

```
var createObject = function(){
var myArray= generateArray();
var myObject = {
    question : myArray[0],
    answerA : myArray[1],
    answerB : myArray[2],
    answerC : myArray[3],
    answerD : myArray[4]
    };
return myObject;
}
```

Comment: It would be more elegant with better indenting. Anyway...if array element 0 is always the `question` and all remaining elements become answers A, B, C, etc., then you could use a loop - but if there are only ever four answers the loop code isn't going to be much shorter, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your background? Python?

```
 var values = generateArray();
 var obj = {};
 ["question", "answerA", "answerB", "answerC", "answerD"].forEach(function(item, idx) {
     obj[item] = values[idx];
 });

 return obj;
```

Comment: Considering the tags are all Javascript tags, and that he's using function(){...} to declare his function, my guess is he's using Javascript. ;-)

Comment: @mbinette I know, I asked for the background ;) It seams like he is not used to js, but surely understand programming..

Comment: @mbinette I specially asked about python, because it provides you some really nice features which can solve such problems in one line..

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question, which is "Convert an array into an object in JavaScript" (see title). I love Python, don't get me wrong, but it's not Javascript.

Comment: Love the functional style of this solution and yes, I'm also doing Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an attribute map:

```js
var createObject = function(){
    // The map should have the attribute names set in order defined in `myArray`
    var map = ["question", "answerA", "answerB", "answerC", "answerD"]
    var myArray = generateArray();
    var myObject = {};
    for(var i in map)
        myObject[map[i]] = myArray[i];
    return myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to go beyond `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'`:

```
  function arrayToObject ( array ) {
    return array.reduce(
      function ( object, cell, index ) {
        if (index > 0) object['answer' + String.fromCharCode(64 + index)] = cell;
        else           object['question'] = cell;
        return object;
      }, {}
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a function that takes an array as an argument, and returns an object, this is how I would do it:

```
var toObject = function(arr) {
  var newObj = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newObj[i] = arr[i];
  }
  return newObj;
};
```

However, keep in mind that Javascript arrays are simply objects with more methods available to them such as `push()`, `pop()`, and the length property.

Hope this helps!